# Fetch URL parameter

Tags: functions, urls

I have an URL `http://127.0.0.1/wordpressbosta/team/?team=teamOne`.

I would like to fetch `team` value `teamOne` in `functions.php` like below.

```
function get_data()
{
    echo json_encode($_GET['team']);    
    die;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_data', 'get_data'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_data', 'get_data');
```

But it is not working.

Comment: What does "not working" mean? In the code, you're adding an ajax handler, but the URL should then be `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`, or not?

Comment: Thanks @kero. I am using `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` as AJAX parameter in JavaScript. How can I fetch `team` value `teamOne` from URL in `functions.php` ?

Comment: In the AJAX handler? You can’t. Not properly anyway. You need to send it with the AJAX request.

Comment: So the URL the user visits is something like `/team/?team=teamOne`, on this you're doing an ajax request. Correct? In the code where you're doing the ajax request, you can also get the query variable and simply pass that to the ajax handler. [See this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144) for how to get query params in JS.

Comment: the URL `/team/?team=teamOne` has GET variables accessed via `$_GET['team']` but your AJAX request is a brand new, completely separate request. Totally disconnected with its own URL etc. Remember, WP is loaded from a complete blank slate one very single request, that includes every page request, every AJAX request, etc etc. You need to pass the data you want in the AJAX request in javascript when you make it, otherwise how would it know?

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. How can I gather it to send with the AJAX request ? Thanks.

Comment: Getting PHP variables in JavaScript in WordPress is a question that’s been asked many times before. You should just search for it.